# The block universe theory

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, time, spacetime-dimensions

i watched a video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A7wk40AeiI regarding the block universe where brian greene seem to be saying we live "forever" (i am probably misinterpreting his words ) can you please clarify if this is true? does he mean we experience our life over and over again "forever"?  i know that in block theory of time there is no distinction between past, present and future and all are on equal footing but this notion of experiencing life again forever is nowhere to be found and our experience of world is from birth to death and we only experience each slice of block universe exactly once and not again and again in loop ( this sounds absurd forgive me).
can you please clarify this confusion?

Comment: If the growing block universe hypothesis is correct, then we wouldn't be able to tell "now" from "now." Thus, you're living your life "forever." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growing_block_universe#Criticism

Comment: We never ever experience same day again and again in a loop it's always the case that it progresses from birth to death there is no doubt about that . Btw thank you for the article it says  " Forrest (2004) argues that although there exists a past, it is lifeless and inactive. Consciousness, as well as the flow of time, is not active within the past and can only occur at the boundary of the block universe in which the present exists". This makes some sense .

Comment: My pleasure! And it may "make sense" in the manner of being logically consistent, but that's insufficient for it to have anything to do with reality. For example, theologians make logically consistent frameworks that have no baring on reality.

Comment: It seems to me that Brian Greene has a following very pleased with speculations about "possibilities" which have some infinitesimal likelihood of them ever becoming observed, and zero relevance to science.